# How can I figure out the UTC offset using Joda?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'd like to end up with a string in the form of `-5:00` (if we're in NY, for example). What's the best way to go about doing this using Joda?

Comment: you need to be more specific -- some city have change offsets in history. It maybe daylight-saving, but not all are daylight-saving.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if it's the *best* way, but here's one method:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ZZ");

DateTimeZone zone;

zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
System.out.println(dtf.withZone(zone).print(0));  // Outputs -08:00

zone = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(-5, 0);
System.out.println(dtf.withZone(zone).print(0)); // Outputs -05:00

DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
System.out.println(dtf.print(dt)); // Outputs -05:00 (time-zone dependent)
```

The example you give doesn't include the leading zero on the hours, though.  If that's what you're really asking (how to exclude the leading zero), then I'm no help.

Comment: That works. Thank you! How can I figure out what the offset is altogether (neverminding the string representation of it)?

Comment: If you've got a joda `DateTime` object, then you can ask for its time zone, then ask the time zone for its offset from UTC in milliseconds (at that particular time).  For example: `long timeZoneOffsetMillis = dt.getZone().getOffset(dt.getMillis());`

Comment: So that gives me something like `-14400000` How can I figure out the hours and minutes from that?

Comment: Assuming the offset is always a multiple of a minute (usually a safe assumption), `long hours = timeZoneOffsetMillis / (1000L*60L*60L);` and `long minutes = (timeZoneOffsetMillis / (1000L*60L)) % 60L;`

Answer (score 3):

### Simple Method for Obtaining Offset in Hours

```
public static String getCurrentTimeZoneOffset() {

    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
    Long instant = DateTime.now().getMillis();

    long offsetInMilliseconds = tz.getOffset(instant);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours( offsetInMilliseconds );
    String offset = Long.toString( hours );

    return offset + " Hours";

}
```

#### Couple caveats:

- This gets the default `DateTimeZone` from **JodaTime**. You can modify it to accept a specific DateTimeZone that is passed into the method.
- This returns it in a format like "-7 Hours" but you can format it as you see fit fairly easily.

Hope that helps.

JP